# Url redirection rule in php & wamp server

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, wamp, redirect, friendly-url

I have URL

```
http://example.com/result.php?search=good&from=1&to=10
```

How can write below URL?

```
http://example.com/result/good/1/10
```

Is it rule for .htaccess? Please help me for redirect url above.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^result/([a-z]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)$ result.php?search=$1&from=$2&to=$3
```

Comment: He made a typo, the second `from` should be a `to`.